# I don't understand writable and configurable property attributes of Objects

Tags: javascript, object, prototype

I don't understand the Writable and Configurable attributes of Objects. For example, in the MDN for [Object.prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype), there is a table where I can clearly see that Configurable, Writable and Enumerable Property Attributes of **Object.prototype** are locked.

However, I can write and extend Object.prototype, for example with the following code:

```
// Example 1
Object.prototype.testing=999;
console.log(Object.testing); // 999

// Example 2
var o = {};
console.log(o.testing); // 999
```

Comment: Duplicate: [Difference between Configurable and Writable attributes of an Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23590502/difference-between-configurable-and-writable-attributes-of-an-object). I know this question has been asked before but linked question has more upvotes and better answers in my opinion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What the MDN is referring to is the property `prototype` of `Object` itself. You cannot overwrite `Object.prototype` itself. If you try and make `Object.prototype` undefined, that will fail:

```
Object.prototype = 1;
console.log(Object.prototype); // [object Object]
```

If you try this in strict mode, you will get a `TypeError` upon attempting to assign to a non-writable property:

```
'use strict';
Object.prototype = 1; // TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'prototype' of function Object() { [native code] }
```

You can write to an object's own properties without changing what the object's reference is, and those have separate attributes. For example, see this:

```
var descriptor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Object.prototype, 'toString');

console.log(descriptor.writable); // true
console.log(descriptor.enumerable); // false
console.log(descriptor.configurable); // true
```

There is a separate `[[Extensible]]` internal property that prevents the creation of new properties on an object -- this is set to `false` if you call `Object.preventExtensions`, `Object.seal` or `Object.freeze`.

Note that it's not a good idea to call `Object.freeze` on something like `Object.prototype`, as really weird things can happen:

```
Object.freeze(Object.prototype);
var building = {};
building.name = 'Alcove Apartments';
building.constructor = 'Meriton Apartments Pty Ltd';
console.log(building.constructor); // function Object() { [native code] }
```

Just like the previous example, it will also throw a `TypeError` in strict mode.

Basically, even though it would be a property on the object itself, it uses the attributes from the prototype chain to check whether or not it can assign the property. This has been [considered as a mistake](http://esdiscuss.org/topic/set-and-inherited-readonly-data-properties) in the language by some people, however others consider this behaviour to be by design.

Comment: Thanks! Basically with Object.freeze I can lock the internal properties of an Object. Why is building.constructor returning undefined? Does it means that some properties of Object.prototype are changed every time you build a new object?

Comment: @Microcipcip: that's some odd behaviour with making prototype properties non-writable, which is why it's not recommended. Basically, even though it would be a property on the object itself, it uses the attributes from the prototype chain to check whether or not it can assign the property.

Comment: @Microcipcip: sorry, my bad -- I meant that it was the default value (`Object`), not `undefined`.

Comment: About your last example, I have found out that if I change `Object.freeze` with `Object.seal()` I can disable the addition of new properties to an object and _keep the existing properties writable_.

Comment: @Microcipcip indeed, that particular quirk is only if the property on the prototype is non-writable.

Answer (score 3):

From: http://ejohn.org/blog/ecmascript-5-objects-and-properties/

Writable: If false, the value of the property can not be changed.

Configurable: If false, any attempts to delete the property or change its attributes (Writable, Configurable, or Enumerable) will fail.

Enumerable: If true, the property will be iterated over when a user does for (var prop in obj){} (or similar).

Answer (score 2):

The Writable, Enumerable and Configurable attributes in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype) appear to be about the `Object.prototype` object itself, not its properties.

So, what that means is that you can't replace `Object.prototype` with a different object, but you are allowed to add properties to it.

So, what that means is if you do this:

```
Object.prototype = {foo: "whatever"};   // doesn't work - is just ignored
var j = {};
console.log(j.foo);   // undefined
```

Then, the first line of code won't do anything.

Answer (score 2):

> I can clearly see that Configurable, Writable and Enumerable Property Attributes of Object.prototype are locked. 
>   However, I can write `Object.prototype`.

No. The writability only concerns the `prototype` property of the `Object` object:

```
Object.prototype = {}; // Error: Invalid assignment (in strict mode)
                       // simply fails in lax mode
```

> And I can extend `Object.prototype`

Yes. You can extend the `Object.prototype` object (regardless how you refer to it); that's a [different attribute](http://es5.github.io/#x8.6.2) (of the object, not of a single property):

```
var proto = Object.getPrototypeOf({});
proto.testing1 = 9999; // works
Object.preventExtensions(proto);
proto.testing2 = 9999; // Error: Invalid assignment (in strict mode)
```