# Difference between Configurable and Writable attributes of an Object

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6, attributes

I saw the following regarding javascript, object data property attributes

—  Configurable: Specifies whether the property can be deleted or changed.

— Enumerable: Specifies whether the property can be returned in a for/in loop.

— Writable: Specifies whether the property can be changed.

Here "Configurable" and "Writable" are representing the same (whether the property can be changed), then why do we need two separate attributes?

Comment: possible duplicate of [I don't understand writable and configurable property attributes of Objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22960493/i-dont-understand-writable-and-configurable-property-attributes-of-objects)

Answer (score 35):

From: http://ejohn.org/blog/ecmascript-5-objects-and-properties/

Writable: If false, the value of the property can not be changed.

Configurable: If false, any attempts to delete the property or change its attributes (Writable, Configurable, or Enumerable) will fail.

Enumerable: If true, the property will be iterated over when a user does for (var prop in obj){} (or similar).

Answer (score 23):

`configurable` and `writable` are NOT representing the same thing.

`configurable` means property *descriptor and existence*.

`writable` means property *value* only.

A property's descriptor contains *value, enumerable, configurable and writable*.

**scenario 1**: create property by *assignment*

```
'use strict';  // non-strict mode behaves slightly different

var foo = {};
foo.bar = 1;  // operated by CreateDataProperty*

// the above is the same as
Object.defineProperty(foo, 'bar', {
  value: 1,
  configurable: true,
  writable: true,
  // ...
});
```

- `CreateDataProperty` is an operation defined together with [ECMAScript spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-createdataproperty).

**scenario 2**: create property by *descriptor*

```
'use strict';  // non-strict mode behaves slightly different

var foo = {};
Object.defineProperty(foo, 'bar', {
  value: 1,
  // configurable => false
  // writable => false
});

foo.bar = 2;    // throw TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property

Object.defineProperty(foo, 'bar', {
  value: 2
  // ...
}); // throw TypeError: Cannot redefine property

delete foo.bar; // throw TypeError: Cannot delete property
```

Answer (score 3):

Configurable prevents any attempts to 'redefine' properties of a key with `Object.defineProperty`, chrome will throw an error sign

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot redefine property: foo

The writable attribute simply avoids this value from being edited

Answer (score 1):

If Writable is set to true means the object property's value can be changed.

If Configurable is set to true, means the object property's type can be changed from data property to accessor property (or vice versa); and the object property can be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

On MDN, I think the [`Object.defineProperty()` documentation answers this question](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty#examples). It's dense reading, but the examples are accessible:

## `writable` attribute:

> ```js
> const o = {}; // Creates a new object
>
> Object.defineProperty(o, "a", {
>   value: 37,
>   writable: false,
> });
>
> console.log(o.a); // 37
> o.a = 25; // No error thrown
> // (it would throw in strict mode,
> // even if the value had been the same)
> console.log(o.a); // 37; the assignment didn't work
>
> // strict mode
> (() => {
>   "use strict";
>   const o = {};
>   Object.defineProperty(o, "b", {
>     value: 2,
>     writable: false,
>   });
>   o.b = 3; // throws TypeError: "b" is read-only
>   return o.b; // returns 2 without the line above
> })();
> ```

## `configurable` attribute:

> ```js
> const o = {};
> Object.defineProperty(o, "a", {
>   get() {
>     return 1;
>   },
>   configurable: false,
> });
>
> Object.defineProperty(o, "a", {
>   configurable: true,
> }); // throws a TypeError
> Object.defineProperty(o, "a", {
>   enumerable: true,
> }); // throws a TypeError
> Object.defineProperty(o, "a", {
>   set() {},
> }); // throws a TypeError (set was undefined previously)
> Object.defineProperty(o, "a", {
>   get() {
>     return 1;
>   },
> }); // throws a TypeError
> // (even though the new get does exactly the same thing)
> Object.defineProperty(o, "a", {
>   value: 12,
> }); // throws a TypeError
> // ('value' can be changed when 'configurable' is false, but only when the property is a writable data property)
>
> console.log(o.a); // 1
> delete o.a; // Nothing happens; throws an error in strict mode
> console.log(o.a); // 1
> ```