# Function inside of for loop not being tested

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I have a function im trying to test:

```
  vm.clearArray = function(){
    for (var id=0; id<vm.copyArray.length;id++){
      vm.styleIcon(vm.copyArray[id],'black')
    }
    vm.copyObjArray = [];
    vm.copyArray = [];
  }
```

I'm trying to test it like:

```
it('should have cleared copyArray on function call', function(){

    var ctrl = $componentController('copy', null);

    spyOn(ctrl, 'clearArray').and.callThrough();
    spyOn(ctrl, 'styleIcon').and.callThrough();

    ctrl.copyArray = [123];
    ctrl.clearArray();

    expect(ctrl.clearArray).toHaveBeenCalled();
    // expect(ctrl.styleIcon).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(ctrl.copyObjArray).toEqual([]);
    expect(ctrl.copyArray).toEqual([]);
  });
```

If I uncomment the above expect I get an error and the vm.styleIcon call is never covered in my coverage report.  By setting copyArray to contain a value in the array I would think that the for loop would then trigger when running the test.  That does not seem to be the case.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have to `spyOn` the `styleIcon()` function?

Comment: Yes @Pointy if I add that in there it still fails.

Comment: Can you set up a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Set up a breakpoint inside the loop and check if the instruction is even called.

Comment: I am not sure but, please, try to move ctrl.copyArray = [123]; just after var ctrl = $componentController('copy', null);

Comment: Where do you define `styleIcon`?

Comment: Please create an example demonstrating the problem on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net) or similar and add a link to it in your question. Currently all we can do is make educated guesses.

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is some kind of inheritance scheme that is causing your error. My assumption is that **your controller is extended by a base controller**.

From what few code I see, I can make two assumptions:

1) **clearArray()** is overridden in the child controller eg.

```
vm.clearArray = function(){
    ...
    vm.copyArray = [];
}
```

so you are trying to test the wrong **clearArray()**

or

2) **ctrl.copyArray** is not writable because of the way inheritance was implemented, eg.

```
function ParentController() {
    var vm = this;
    vm.copyArray = [];
    vm.copyObjArray = [];
    vm.clearArray = function() {
        for (var id=0; id<vm.copyArray.length;id++){
            vm.styleIcon(vm.copyArray[id],'black')
        }
        vm.copyObjArray = [];
        vm.copyArray = [];
    }

    vm.styleIcon = function(index, color) {
    }
};

function ChildController() {
    ParentController.call(this);
}

ChildController.prototype = Object.create(ParentController.prototype, {copyArray:{ value: [] } });

var ctrl = new ChildController();
```

Using the above will yield the error, copyArray is defined as a non writable property, so line:

```
ctrl.copyArray = [123];
```

does not change its value.

- [Object.defineProperty()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)
- [Difference between Configurable and Writable attributes of an Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23590502/difference-between-configurable-and-writable-attributes-of-an-object)

Anyway, without more of the code, it is difficult to get what is causing the error.

Answer (score 0):

The code of the loop looks good, so I think that the property `vm.copyArray` might not be set at all. If you add a `console.log(vm.copyArray)`, what is the result?

Perhaps vm and `$componentController('copy', null)` are not references to the same object, but call each other's functions through some library? is there any other way to reference `vm` from the test script, rather than using `$componentController('copy', null)`?

Your loop must be triggered when you pass the array in the function as an argument. Of course your actually code will fail unless the pass `vm.copyArray` as an argument in the actual code, but it will show you if the loop is the problem, or the reference to the vm from the test script:

```
//tested function
 vm.clearArray = function(copyArray){
    for (var id=0; id<copyArray.length;id++){
      vm.styleIcon(copyArray[id],'black')
    }
  }

//test
ctrl.clearArray([123]);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to determine the exact reason because you've shown a sample taken straight from your test, and not a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also, you didn't specify what the error(s) or `expect` results are, so we're going off very limited information.

That said, I strongly suspect `vm` is undefined/null or not a prototype instantiatable through `$componentController`. If this is the case, you should be receiving an error at `spyOn(ctrl, 'clearArray').and.callThrough()` or `ctrl.clearArray()`, never running the loop and thus never calling `vm.styleIcon`. In this scenario you'd need to verify that `ctrl` is in fact an instance of whatever prototype `vm` is a part of(is it actually a global variable?).

If this is not the case and both the `vm` prototype is correct and `$componentController('copy', null);` is creating the object you think it is, perhaps `styleIcon` is undefined/null, unable to be called and creating essentially the same problem. In this scenario, ensure `styleIcon` is set and that it's the function you think it is.

When all else fails, debuggers are your friend.

Please specify what the error(s) are and where they're occuring(in more detail) for a better answer.