# Object.defineProperty to override read-only property

Tags: javascript, node.js, properties, ecmascript-6, prototype

In our NodeJS application, we define custom error classes by extending the default Error object:

```
"use strict";
const util = require("util");

function CustomError(message) {
    Error.call(this);
    Error.captureStackTrace(this, CustomError);
    this.message = message;
}

util.inherits(CustomError, Error);
```

This allows us to `throw CustomError("Something");` with the stack trace showing up correctly, and both `instanceof Error` and `instanceof CustomError` working correctly.

However, for returning errors in our API (over HTTP), we want to convert the error to JSON. Calling `JSON.stringify()` on an Error results in `"{}"`, which is obviously not really descriptive for the consumer.

To fix this, I thought of overriding `CustomError.prototype.toJSON()`, to return an object literal with the error name and message. `JSON.stringify()` would then just stringify this object and all would work great:

```
// after util.inherits call

CustomError.prototype.toJSON = () => ({
    name    : "CustomError",
    message : this.message
});
```

However, I quickly saw that this throws a `TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'toJSON' of Error`. Which might make sense as I'm trying to write to the prototype. So I changed the constructor instead:

```
function CustomError(message) {
    Error.call(this);
    Error.captureStackTrace(this, CustomError);
    this.message = message;
    this.toJSON = () => ({
        name    : "CustomError",
        message : this.message
    });
}
```

This way (I expected), the CustomError.toJSON function would be used and the CustomError.prototype.toJSON (from Error) would be ignored.

Unfortunately, this just throws the error upon object construction: `Cannot assign to read only property 'toJSON' of CustomError`.

Next I tried removing `"use strict";` from the file, which *sort of* solved the problem in that no error was being thrown anymore, although the `toJSON()` function was not used by `JSON.stringify()` at all.

At this point I'm just desperate and just try random things. Eventually I end up with using `Object.defineProperty()` instead of directly assigning to `this.toJSON`:

```
function CustomError(message) {
    Error.call(this);
    Error.captureStackTrace(this, CustomError);
    this.message = message;
    Object.defineProperty(this, "toJSON", {
        value: () => ({
            name    : "CustomError",
            message : this.message
        })
    });
```

This works perfectly. In strict mode, no errors are being called, and `JSON.stringify()` returns `{"name:" CustomError", "message": "Something"}` like I want it to.

So although it works as I want it to now, I still want to know:

1. Why does this work exactly? I expect it to be the equivalent to `this.toJSON = ...` but apparently it is not.
2. Should it work like this? I.e. is it safe to depend on this behaviour?
3. If not, how should I override the toJSON method correctly? (if possible at all)

Comment: Take a look at [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22960493/i-dont-understand-writable-and-configurable-property-attributes-of-objects/22960738#22960738) and see if that is what you're asking about. Thanks!

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy That's pretty weird behaviour indeed, but at least explains why I can't assign to the property normally. What I still don't get from the [linked article](https://esdiscuss.org/topic/set-and-inherited-readonly-data-properties) in your comment: does `Object.defineProperty` work (i.e. override read-only prototype properties anyway) by design or is this unexpected behaviour upon I should not rely?

Comment: I'm getting a `TypeError: Cannot redefine property: xxxx`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why does this work exactly?

`Object.defineProperty` just defines a property (or alters its attributes, if it already exists and is configurable). Unlike an assignment `this.toJSON = …` it does not care about any inheritance and does not check whether there is an inherited property that might be a setter or non-writable.

> Should it work like this? I.e. is it safe to depend on this behaviour?

Yes, and yes. Probably you can even use it on the prototype.

---

For your actual use case, given a recent node.js version, use an ES6 class that `extends Error` for the best results.

Answer (score 1):

Since I noticed you using the arrow function I'm going to assume you have access to ES6, meaning you have access to classes too.

You can just simply extend the `Error` class. For example:

```
class CustomError extends Error {
    toJSON() {
        return {
            name: 'CustomError',
            message: this.message
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Good point, that looks much cleaner! Still, why does this (and using `Object.defineProperty`) work and trying to set `this.toJSON` does not?

Comment: I'm not quite sure actually, can't reproduce on Node 4.x.

Answer (score 0):

If you truly need to use components or other React features inside your `<template>` element you can fix the React to render in `content` by monkey-patching a few of DOM methods of HTMLTemplateElement.

```js
HTMLTemplateElement.prototype.appendChild = function (child) {
  return this.content.appendChild(child);
}

HTMLTemplateElement.prototype.removeChild = function (child) {
  return this.content.removeChild(child);
}

Object.defineProperty(HTMLTemplateElement.prototype, "firstChild", {
  get() {
    return this.content.firstChild;
  }
})
```

I was able to render anything inside a template element after this. The `appendChild` and `removeChild` is mandatory because it will be used for render but if you're not using hydration you may not need the `firstChild` patch.